# Is there a way to know when and in what plug-in Eclipse service is registered?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

It's nice that Eclipse uses service oriented architecture more and more, but am I only the developer who sees the lack of knowledge of **by what plug-in** and **at what stage** service is registered as a problem?

Consider example:

```
IServiceLocator someServiceLocator = ...
SomeService someService = (SomeService)someServiceLocator.getService(SomeService.class);
// oops, someService is null
```

Possible reasons to why `someService` is `null` are:

- Some plug-in that registers this service doesn't present or not loaded
- Service wasn't registered yet

How should one resolve this? Are there any tools?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: there are no tools available.

For the complete list of services and where they are registered do "Call Hierarchy" on `ServiceLocator.registerService(Class api, Object service)`.

For a good list of the available global services, look at `Workbench.initializeDefaultServices()`. There are some additional services that are only available at the window or workbench part level.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what plugins are installed and started, you can use the OSGI console and see the state of the plugins.

So if you are looking for a service "XService", find the plugin which contains the service and look for the plugin state on the OSGI console.

Start you application with `-console` option and type `ss` on the osgi console. This is not straight forward but works.

Comment: Finding relevant plug-in that registers service is not straight forward. Secondly, the service can be registered after plug-in starts. For example, when workbench is created.